# Search multiple directories, delete duplicate files

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a directory of files that contain files of records.  I just got access to a new directory that has the same records but additional files as well, but the additional files are buried deep inside other folders and i cant find them.
So my solution would be to have a python program run and delete all files that are duplicates in the two different directories (and subdirectories), and leave others intact, which will give me the "new files" i'm looking for.

I have seen a couple of programs that find duplicates, but i'm unsure as to how they run really, and they haven't been helpful.

Any way i can accomplish what i'm looking for?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach:

1. Create a set of MD5 hashes from your original folder.
2. Recursively MD5 hash the files in your new folder, deleting any files that generate hashes already present in your set.

Caveat to the above is that there is a chance two different files can generate the same hash. How different are the files?

Comment: Arguably, the chance that two different files generate the same hash is negligible. At least, considering all the research that is going on trying to find these cases, it's pretty certain that it is not going to happen accidentaly.

Answer (score 1):

use fslint or some similar software. Fslint is able to for example give you a list of the different files and hardlink the copies together, or delete the duplicates. One option is also to just use a diff-like program to diff the directories if their internal structure is the same.

Comment: Is there an Fslint for windows?

Comment: i dont think there is fslint, but there certainly are alternatives. google for "fslint windows" and you will get  a ton of hits.

Answer (score 0):

Do they duplicate files in both directories have the same name/path? If I understand correctly you want to find the duplicate filenames rather than file contents? If so, a 'synchronised' call to os.walk in both trees might be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately i know very little about "calling" things.  I know python programming but don't know anything about dealing with hashes and such.
My files will have the same names, but will be in different directories.  My goal is to find the "new" files, i.e. the files that aren't duplicates